# what is the difference between CBCharateristicWithResponse and CBChatracteristicWithoutResponse in CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a command to BLE peripheral device like this.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
if(error) {
    //        [self cleanup];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

unsigned char bytes[] = {0xA0,0x05,0xF1,0xF2,0xCC,0xFE};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:self.mutableData];
data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kServiceUUID]]) {
    for(CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kWriteCharactersticUUID]]) {
            self.discoveredCharacteristic = characteristic;
            [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        } else if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kNotifyCharactersticUUID]]) {
            self.notifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But, If I am writing like this the other delegate methods are not debugging. And If I use `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`, I am getting an error like this

Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted."
 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}

I tested the BLE device with LightBlue Application, It is showing like, The property is for Write Without Response.

Can you please anyone help me with this?

Comment: Each characteristic can declare what kind of write operations it allows: *write without response*, ie. writes without feedback that the data has arrived, and *writes with response*, *signed write*, *queued write* etc.. So you characteristic obviously only supports *write without response*. What is your problem with it? What do you mean by *the other delegate methods are not debugging*?

Comment: I am unable to send the data to the BLE Device and didWriteValueForCharacteristic,  didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic these all methods are not executing. the debugging stops after the didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService method. I updated my question with full code for clarification. Please check it once.

Comment: `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` is called when the response for the write operation has been received. But the characteristic doesn't support responses. `didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic` will be called for notification state changes; but you don't initiate any such changes. `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` will be called if you read a characteristics or have change notifications enabled. So it is by design that the delegates aren't called. And what do you mean by "I am unable to send the data"? Do you get an error message? What do you expect to happen and what happes instead?

Comment: @Codo Thanks for your support. It's working fine.